# Best way to know if the text included in a java string contains characters in UTF-8 encoding or not

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

is there any other way to know if the `java` `String` contains `character-encoding`  in `UTF-8` encoding or not ,like the Arabic words  for example .

i tried this code : but does it accurate and make the job ?

```
char c = 'أ';
int num = (int) c;

if(num> 128)
// then UTF-8 characters exists
```

Comment: `> 128` is not UTF-8 specific. It just means non-ASCII. Is "non-ASCII" what you're trying to test for?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `String` in UTF-8 encoding in Java. Strings are *always* UTF-16 there.

Comment: http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/ may help.

Comment: @Joey i know that i asked if it contains a character in UTF-8

Comment: Nammari, then the answer is obviously no. Always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming UTF-8 == non-ASCII)

What you could do is encode then decode the string in ASCII and compare the result of that with the original. If they're not equal, there are non-ASCII characters.

However, your own sample would work too (almost, should be `>= 128`), because the following proves that indeed all `char`s `< 128` are ASCII:

> To allow backward compatibility, the 128 ASCII and 256 ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) characters are assigned Unicode/UCS code points that are the same as their codes in the earlier standards.

> The first plane (code points U+0000 to U+FFFF) contains the most frequently used characters and is called the Basic Multilingual Plane or BMP. Both UTF-16 and UCS-2 encode valid code points in this range as single 16-bit code units that are numerically equal to the corresponding code points.

("UTF-16" and "ASCII", Wikipedia)

And `char`s are UTF-16 "code units".

---

However, judging from the question in its entirety, you might be better off reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) first.

Comment: All legal UTF-16 strings can be encoded as legal UTF-8 strings without lossage. Just don’t generate braindamaged CESU-8.

Comment: @tchrist I know, but eh, what do you mean to say? :P UTF-8 is not relevant to my answer at all (see first line)

Comment: My comment was supposed to go on the other answer, not yours; sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Java (internally) always encodes a `String` in UTF-16 independent of its content. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

You can convert it to any supported encoding, including ASCII and UTF-8, but may lose characters that are not displayable in the selected encoding.

Depending on why you check, you could convert the string to ASCII and read it back into a java String and see if they match. If they do, ASCII suffices for storing your string. This would be the most obvious check for later readers of your source code.

You can also compare the unicode codepoint of every character against 128, if they are all <= 127 the string is ASCII compatible, i.e. does certainly not contain arabic. To get the unicode codepoint for a character of your string use `str.codePointAt(index)`.

If you explicitly want to find arabic text you should explicitly check for arabic characters. Otherwise you could get false positives for french, german or many other languages that use accented characters. Fortunately the Unicode consortium associates blocks per language, so that the check likely boils down to <strike>`cp >= beginningOfUnicodeBlock && cp <= endOfUnicodeBlock`</strike>.

**Edit,** hinted by tchrist: There are `java.lang.Character.UnicodeBlock` and `java.lang.Character.UnicodeScript`. The latter was added in Java 7. Both can be used to classify unicode code points.

```
int cp = str.codePointAt(index);
if (UnicodeScript.ARABIC.equals(UnicodeScript.of(cp)) {
    // arabic character found
}
```

Comment: You can’t use `char` variables in that way. Unicode code points are `int`.

Comment: Also, you want to test scripts not blocks.  See the Java **7** `Character` and `Pattern` classes, or just use the ICU `UCharacter` class, which is far more suited to this kind of work.

Comment: I edited to post to use codepoint instead of character. Testing for script sounds good, but depending on the use case testing on block would likely suffice. I wasn't aware of ICU, which would apparently add an external dependency. Also I wasn't aware of Java 7's `Character.UnicodeScript` nor of `Character.UnicodeBlock` which was added in 1.2.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there's a definitive way to know with 100% accuracy. UTF-8 and UTF-16 can come with an optional [Byte Order Mark](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom4) which you can detect. There's no guarantee it'll be there, but a lot of tools include them, especially for UTF-16 as it's more important.

Apache Commons IO includes a handy [BOMInputStream class](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/BOMInputStream.html) for reading BOM marked streams which is simple to use:

```
BOMInputStream bomIn = new BOMInputStream(in);
if (bomIn.hasBOM()) {
    // has a UTF-8 BOM
}
```